# how does the find method exactly work in BeautifulSoup using a LXML parser?

Tags: beautifulsoup

[a snap of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QCXJ.png)

i was trying to use find() method to excerpt info from an html element, but it shows find() takes no arguments

Error:
5 review = soup.find_all('article', itemprop = 'review')
6 for review in reviews:
----> 7     date_flown = review.find('td', class_ = 'review-value ')
8     if date_flown:
9         print(date_flown)

TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]!

Comment: can you paste your code instead of screenshot?

Comment: You should make it as easy as possible for others to provide an answer, e.g. formatting your question (especially distinguish between you stating the problem and code and messages) and providing the non-working code so others can try it out. You state "`find()` takes no argument" but the message says "no keyword argument" so `find(.., key=..)` is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

> ```py
> review = soup.find_all('article', itemprop = 'review') ## should be reviews!!
> for review in reviews:
> ```

I think you meant to write `reviews = soup.find_all('article', itemprop = 'review')` not `review=....` and that might be why `review.find` is behaving unexpectedly